# ASP.NET Webform Routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms, asp.net-routing

We are building a products site and are using Routes in ASP.NET WebForms C#.
We currently have

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}/{subCategoryname}", "~/SubCategory.aspx");
```

It works great ..

*Shoes/Womens , Shoes/Kids , Boots/Mens , Boots/Womens.*

We added a new Route in hopes to get the following resutls

*Product/Mountain-Light-Mens-Hiking-Boots*

So we now our Router has

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}/{subCategoryname}", "~/SubCategory.aspx"); 
routes.MapPageRoute("", "Product/{productName}", "~/Product.aspx");
```

However, when we go to */Product/Mountain-Light-Mens-Hiking-Boots* the Router fires **SubCategory.aspx**, which is not what we want to happen. We would like the **Product.aspx** to fire up.

I understand that the Router does not know if 'Prodcut' is a categoryName or not.

How do I add another root level Routing for /Products ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code order like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "Product/{productName}", "~/Product.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}/{subCategoryname}", "~/SubCategory.aspx"); 
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
```

Order is very important. Because you enter url like "www.domain.com/abc/abc" and if

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}/{subCategoryname}", "~/SubCategory.aspx");
```

at third no. then this route never called. it call following route.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{categoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
```

And value will be.

```
string Value= Page.RouteData.Values["categoryName"].ToString();
Value= "abc/abc";
```

So, Url Pattern that Contain one Parameter should be at the and Route Collection.